# Test-driven development (TDD) in .NET Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit

I am beginner in .NET, how can I install NUnit test in Visual Studio 2010?

I have tried this:

```
PM> install-package Nunit
```

But I get this error message:

```
Install-Packag : The schema version of 'NUnit' is incompatible with version 1.2.20325.9034 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.
Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 16
+ Install-Package <<<<  NUnit
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the error message....click the link to go and upgrade NuGet to the latest version. Then try again.

Or, go to nunit.org, download the NUnit DLL files and then reference them in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to menu *Tools* → *Extension Manager* in the Visual Studio IDE and uninstall the extension. Then restart Visual Studio and reinstall the extension.

Comment: That was supposed to refer to the installed extension.